# Is my analysis of a closet system (rails hanging from a top track) correct? (e.g. Elfa, IKEA Algot, or floating shelf on L brackets)

Tags: safety, shelving, drywall-anchor, closet

So my contractor didn't use the supplied anchors from the closet company (Elfa), and now I don't know if the random anchors they used will hold up, and wanted to know if I should re-mount the tracks with better anchors.

[image: Representative picture of the system]

*(This is a representative pic from the site in the watermark--Red circles are where I may support rails from the bottom with a block of wood or something, since they almost touch my square baseboard)*

More pictures of the system: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqIND.jpg

After a bunch of research, and using these links as resources:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/601974/is-this-the-right-way-to-calculate-the-force-on-a-screw

Physics - Mechanics: Ch 15 Torque (20 of 25) More Examples: 2 F=? of Screw on Bracket - iLecture Online
https://youtu.be/kkgj5QBF_Tc

I drew this diagram of forces (free body diagram?):

[image: Diagram of system]

I simplified the actual closet system to one with just one anchor and one rail (assuming weight will be evenly distributed). Point A, the bottom of the rail is the point of rotation.

(Please tell me if this approach is ok for the purposes of this analysis)

And made [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17GraxAQ-8ZTfvSNoZAkI1bP1jNaSrXUi6Yi9HulemU0/edit?usp=sharing) to help calculate things using the torque/moment formula:

T = F * d

And that the sum of T should be 0.

F1 = force on shelf (assume at front edge)
F2 = force on anchor

Then, F1 x d1 = F2 x d2

F2 = F1 x (d1/d2)

My results are that with a 50lb rated anchor I should be able to support at least 100lbs safely (dividing the formula result by 2 for safety) on that anchor-- **does this seem right?**

The rails are very long (80") so I suppose that plays into it, but want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

If this is correct, then basically it means that the closet system should be fine on even average 50lb rated drywall anchors, and if I use heavy duty toggle bolts, there should be no worries under typical closet loads?

EDIT:

It occurred to me after posting this that perhaps what I'm missing is the vertical shear force on the anchor? If I support the rails from the bottom (so the rails are basically sitting on the wood baseboard), that would eliminate that concern, right?

EDIT 2:

After having a chance to get on-site and take a closer look, found a few things:

1. Does not appear that any anchors are in the studs, will go back this weekend to check again with an endoscope, cut open the drywall or use finish nails to double check.
2. It seems the top tracks were glued onto the wall, after removing all screws in the track, I cannot budge it, even prying with a screwdriver. The main reason I would remove it is to remount right-side up, but the only difference would be some cut out slots that let you slide in rails from the top. I was able to get rails in from the bottom, and can leave it upside down as long as there's no concern for bending the small portion of the rail that's next to the slots. (Can see in picture)
3. My new plan is to drill another hole or two through the top track to get into metal studs once I locate them, and secure with snap toggles. And also find something to place on the baseboards to support the rails from the bottom (any ideas? coins? folded paper/cardboard?). Any other issues I'm missing with this plan?

More pictures of the top tracks and my setup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T7N7.jpg

Thanks for everyone's replies!

---

Comment: Key question/information missing? what anchor type did they use ?? picture please

Comment: what is the spacing between vertical rails

Comment: What anchors did the contractor use, and what type did the instructions call for?  Examine that and not all the mumbo jumbo.

Comment: I would probably toss the anchors and just use #10 or #12  2 inch or 2 1/2 inch screws into the studs.  No math needed and should hold a tank.

Comment: After re-reading the question, I imagine what I said in my comment, was what your contractor did.  This is why they did not use the anchors.  Anchors in drywall is usually the least good idea to do if you can't use studs.  Drywall is not that strong to count on to hold heavy weight.

Comment: @crip659 From what I could see it looked like drywall anchors (I had to remove a screw to be able to slide a rail over it). It's on my list to check for studs. I am not confident that the worker who installed the tracks would have tried to hit studs, since they installed the tracks upside down, also the tracks have fixed holes and are cut to perfectly fit on the back wall so I don't know that any holes line up with studs.

Comment: @JACK I don't know what anchors they used. I can only assume the cheapest they could find since they didn't use the ones from Elfa I supplied. There is at least 24" between railings.

Comment: @Ruskes No idea what anchors the contractor's worker used. 24" between railings

Comment: @vlotty  It does not make sense to buy cheap anchors when they had free anchors already there.  They either looked at the free Elfa anchors and saw they were not good enough and used better ones,or they found the studs.

Comment: **you are not listening**. We want to know the spacing between the screws, not between the railings

Comment: @crip659 They did not open the box that had the anchors, and I wasn't around to monitor unfortunately. I don't have wood studs, there are metal studs, and I think the best way to mount to those is using a toggle?

Comment: @Ruskes Sorry, I didn't see the question about how far apart the screwholes in the track are. They are spaced approx 7" apart.

Comment: The vertical rails hang from the top horizontal support. Which often can be screwed directly into the header. Rock solid - we have several such setups heavily loaded still up years later.

Comment: I think that some pictures of _your_ actual installation will help tremendously - if you think about it, a picture of how it's supposed to be installed (but, apparently, isn't) doesn't help much. Show us where the screws go into the wall, what kind of anchors are used (or not). A nice overview and a couple of detail shots. Then, if asked, provide more as necessary.

Comment: @FreeMan Just added some info and uploaded more pics.

Answer (score 2):

Using bottom screws will defeat the purpose of hanging adjustable space rack.

Insert small piece of foam between the rack and wall to prevent scratches.

Starting from the corner of the room, measure 16 inch, and observe if there is a screw in the top rail.

Repeat measurement for next screw and so on.

That would indicate they used studs (and no anchors), which would be the strongest hold.

Comment: I was thinking of supporting from the bottom with a block of wood or something, rather than bottom screws. Point A is just where the rails touch the wall.

Comment: @vlotty please measure the spacing between the screws, not between the railing.

Comment: @ruskes is right that the elfa system relies on the top rail to support the load. Screws in studs (or possibly the top plate) in the rail are more than adequate. Elfa’s supplied drywall fasteners are fancy, but they are really only holding the uprights in alignment.

Comment: @Ruskes Sorry, I misunderstood-- I will be on site this weekend to check for where the screws are and measuring to see if they line up with where studs should be (and will bring a stud finder just in case). Appreciate the answer

Comment: @Ruskes Just added an edit-- did not appear that any current screws hit any metal studs